# Javascript - functions/loops/console.log

Tags: javascript

I am very new to coding and it's been fun so far. But I've been trying to work a function and for loop together and have it print out with console.log. Is anything at all correct? Or am I just completely lost?

What I want it to do is have bottlesLeft have a value of 99.
Declare a function named 'bottleStockReporter'.
Inside the function use console.log() to print out how many bottles of root beer are on the wall. "99 bottles of root beer on the wall. 99 bottles of root beer."
Use a while loop to call your new function for the value of 'bottlesLeft' and decrease 'bottlesLeft' by 1 each time.

This is what I have so far:

```
var bottleStockReporter = function(number)
{
    var bottlesLeft = 99;
    console.log(bottlesLeft) + "bottles of root beer on the wall." + (bottlesLeft) + "bottles of root beer on the wall.";
    for(var bottlesLeft = 99; bottleLeft>0; bottlesLeft = bottlesLeft --);
};
bottleStockReporter(99);
```

my output prints out the number 99

Comment: thats not Java code, it looks like Javascript.  I've edited your tags.

Comment: No, I'm not in school anymore. But I am trying to answer study questions to learn to code. I have been using Code school/code academy/ looking at online resources/etc

Comment: Well if the solution requires you to use a `while` loop then you shouldn't be using a `for` loop.

Comment: If you're learning, you might appreciate a good [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution. Basically, you pass a number, bottlesLeft is set to that number, and we loop downwards and output to the console.

Here's your challenge: Test this function. What if you pass a non-number? What if a string is passed? What if a negative number is passed? How do you account for these cases?

```
var bottleStockReporter = function(number) {
  for(var bottlesLeft = number; bottlesLeft>0; bottlesLeft--) {
    console.log(bottlesLeft + " bottles of root beer on the wall. " + (bottlesLeft) + " bottles of root beer on the wall.");
  }
};

bottleStockReporter(99); //Loops 99 times
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably change
`var bottlesLeft = 99;` to `var bottlesLeft = number;`. This way, when you call `bottleStockReporter(`some number`);`, `bottlesLeft` will not be set to 99 every time. In addition, your `for` loop will set `bottlesLeft` to 99 again, so you should change it to look like:

```
for (var num = bottlesLeft; num >= 0; num--) {
    console.log(num + " bottles of beer on the wall. " + num + " bottles of beer.");
}
```

In the end, something like this:

```
function bottleStockReporter(number) {
    for (var num = number; num >= 0; num--) {
        console.log(num + " bottles of root beer on the wall.");
    }
}
bottleStockReporter(99);
```

If you want to be extra fancy and not output `1 bottles of beer` you could do:

```
function bottleStockReporter(number) {
    for (var num = number; num >= 0; num--) {
        var str = " bottles ";
        if (num == 1) {
            str = " bottle ";
        }
        console.log(num + str + "of root beer on the wall.");
    }
}
bottleStockReporter(99);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first start by following the problem statement.

> Declare a function named `bottleStockReporter`

```
function bottleStockReporter() {

}
```

> Use console.log to print out how many bottles of root on the wall.

Kind of ambigous, but lets assume that the function `bottleStockReporter` takes as a parameter the number of bottles left:

```
function bottleStockReporter(bottlesLeft) {
    console.log(bottlesLeft + " bottles of beer on the wall. " + bottlesLeft + " bottles of beer.");  
}
```

> Use a while loop to call your new function for the value of 'bottlesLeft' and decrease 'bottlesLeft' by 1 each time.

Assuming there are 99 bottles:

```
var bottles = 99;
while(bottles > 0) { //While loop. Call the function while bottles is positive.
   bottleStockReporter(bottles); //Call function 'bottles' times
   bottles--; //Decrease bottles
}
```

And there you go.

Answer (score 0):

But what about the grammatical concordance?

```
function bottleStockReporter(i) {
    for(var i = 99; i>0; i--) {
        var bottleOrBottles = (i > 1) ? " bottles" : " bottle";         
        console.log(i + bottleOrBottles + " of root beer on the wall.");            
    }
}

bottleStockReporter(99);
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for all the great advice and links. I still have a loooong way to go but it's exciting! thanks!

Comment: No problem: you are beginning in the right way. Cheers!